# Help with rewording my sentence? Or is it fine as is?

Tags: phrase-usage

Here’s my sentence: “Trying to guess why she’d floundered the attempt would be like taking a shot in the dark.”

Here’s the meaning of ‘take a shot in the dark’ from the Cambridge Dictionary website:

> An attempt to guess something when you have no information or knowledge about the subject and therefore cannot possibly know what the answer is

My problem with this: It seems to me that because the phrase ‘take a shot in the dark’ already implies that something is being guessed, I should rephrase my sentence to leave out saying that the character is ‘trying to guess’ something and only use the phrase itself, but I can’t figure out how to reword it.

If anyone can help me reword the sentence, I would really appreciate it. Or, if I’m just overthinking this and it seems alright as is, please let me know.

Comment: No, it's fine because taking a shot in the dark is metaphorical.

Comment: You can't use *flounder* like that: it's an **intransitive** verb. Did you perhaps mean "flunked"?

Comment: I agree, but I'd also drop the unidiomatic simile-ising 'like': << Any attempt to explain why she failed is just a shot in the dark. >>

Comment: Chappo, I used floundered as a way to say she ‘messed up’ the attempt. I didn’t know it was intransitive, but thanks for telling me; I’ll be sure to change that. And Edwin, I agree and thought about dropping that, too, but just wanted to figure out what to do with that phrase before I cleaned up anything else in the sentence. I was really stumped; pretty much had a brain fart :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, "floundered" is wrong.  "Flounder" is intransitive. You can't "flounder" something.  Maybe it's a typo and you mean "foundered," metaphorically relating the situation to a sinking ship, but then you'd be mixing metaphors.  So maybe you mean "flubbed." Or maybe you mean "floundered" and "the attempt" is what needs to go.  I don't know.  Whatever the case, you need to change "floundered" or omit "the attempt."

Second of all, there's nothing ungrammatical about saying it that way, but it's wordy. You can omit "like."  You can also omit "taking."  You can also change "trying to guess" to just "guessing."

Third of all, there's nothing showing the pluperfect is appropriate, but I'm going to assume that it is, that this is appearing in some past context where the action of the verb is to be in the past of that past context.  If not, change "she'd" to just "she."

> Guessing why she floundered would be a shot in the dark.